# Java String class instances are constants

Tags: java, string

this is probably an easy question but not for me at this stage.

I read that (I quote) "All instances of the String class are constants, meaning they cannot be changed after they have been created. But strings can be replaced".

This is confusing. What does it mean that a String variable cannot be changed but the string can?

Can anyone please give me code example where we would try to change the variable but fail?

Cheers for the help.

Comment: strings are immutable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Comment: I think its becoz, u cannot typecast String to any other type. Its state is constant once you create.

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
String myString = "Hi!";
```

You're doing two things. The first one is defining a reference called *myString* the second one is creating a String Object. That String Object contains "Hi!", and there isn't a way to change that. In other words, there isn't a `set` method to change the string:

```
myString.set("another content");
```

However, you can create a new Object and change your `myString` reference to point to it. The important thing to get is that your *myString* isn't the String Object itself but just a reference to it.

```
myString = "New content";
```

When you do that, the old String is not pointed by any variable any more and is a candidate for garbage collection. Also any other operation on the String, such as substring, uppercase, etc. will create a new String Object.

When an Object can't be changed after being created is called *Immutable*. In Java Strings are not only immutable, but also final, so that you can't subclass a String to change its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Strings aren't constants, they're ***immutable***, which is something else altogether. It means that you cannot modify the contents of string object, but you can make a new one based on the first, e.g.

```
String hw = "hello world";
hw.ToUpperCase();
```

The latter doesn't change the original string `hw` but creates a new string with all characters to uppercase.

Comment: And as pointed out by others, you can do a hw = "new string" and that would work, but it would be a new memory allocation. The older memory reference where "hello world" was residing is now considered garbage and is collected.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean that a String variable cannot be changed but the string can?

Actually the text that you quoted means the exact opposite of that.

A String variable can be assigned to (i.e. replaced).  Example is:

```
String s = "first";
s = "second";
```

This replaces the reference to "first" with a reference to "second".

I can't give you a legitimate example of changing the contents / state of a String because you can't do it<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* Actually, you *can* do it by breaking a String object's encapsulation using reflection.  But it is a really, really bad idea.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is this: in Java [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) is an [immutable object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

As previously stated by fellow programmers - you may change the reference, yes, but you may never change an immutable object (it is guaranteed not to be possible to change it).